# Line editor (more text here)

Tags: code-golf

In the misty years of yore, when fanfold terminals walked the earth, there lived a strange creature. Oddly crippled and yet oddly powerful, the line editor teemed across the programming landscape in untold numbers; covering the earth as far as the eye could see.

Now it is fallen on hard times. That vast population hunted, hounded, and driven to the brink of extinction. Only a few specimens remain, most in cramped and unembelished cages in the less enlightened kind of zoo, though a few stuffed and mounted examples can be seen in backwater museums. Oh, and there is [`ed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29).

**Frankenstein-like, we shall resurrect the noble beast!**

### Commands

Our editor is fairly minimal and will support the following commands

**Focus moving commands**

- `<number>[,<number>]` -- move the focus to the stated line and if the second argument is given to the state column. Excessive line number gets the last line. Excessive column number gets the end of the line.
- `,<number>` -- move to column number on the current line
- `e` -- move the focus to the end of the file but do not begin a new line.
- `b` -- move the focus to the beginning of the file.

**Informational commands**

- `L` -- Echo the current context. The five lines centered on the current line are printed. All five lines are indented by one character; the current line is marked with a ">", the others with a " ". Under these lines another line is printed consisting entirely of spaces except for a "^" in the current column (a total of six lines are printed).
- `l` -- echo the current line
- `p [[<start>],[<end>]]` -- Print the file from starting to ending address. These value default to 1 and 0 (the end of the file).

**File altering commands**

- `A [<text>]` -- Move to the line beyond the end of the file (that is begin a new line) and (possibly) append text.
- `<return>` (alone) -- Insert a newline. Thus `a <return> <return>` inserts a newline after the current one.
- `r <text>` -- replaces everything from the focus to the end of the line with text.
- `i [<text>]` -- inserts text followed by by newline at the current focus. Any portion of this line beyond the focus ends up on the next line.
- `I <text>` -- inserts text at the current focus, preserving the rest of the line. Focus remains on this line.
- `d` -- Delete the contents of the current line or if the current line is already empty, remove the line.
- `j` -- join this line to the next

Of this last group the first four end with the focus moving to the next line, while `I` preserves the focus at the end of the added text. When deleting or joining focus remains at the same line and column *number*.

**The Interpretation of line numbers in commands**

Number beginning with '+' or '-' are interpreted as *offsets* from the current line number. Numbers without a sign are interpreted as absolute line numbers, except that '0' means the last line of the file.

### Prompt and interaction

The editor functions as a shell, and the prompt has the form `<line>','<column>'>'` where line is the line number except that "end" is used when the focus is at the last character of the file.

Each command is accepted only when the user presses newline. And takes affect.

Readline support is allowed but not required.

No feedback is provided except the changing values of  and  in the prompt, unless explicitly stated in the commands description.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

#### Special thanks to dmkee for making this in sandbox where I adopted it.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/12651#12651)

Comment: What if there are less than 5 lines and `L` is called?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Everything borks

Comment: Actually you just A. Error. B do what you can with what you have, C do nothing, Choose any

Comment: Hello, I downvoted this challenge because personally I find it to not be extremely well defined, to not be extremely interesting, and also to have quite strict runtime requirements. For example, many languages are not able to perform I/O in that manner, such as almost all golfing languages. Additionally, the format for the entire challenge makes me wonder if this was designed to be good for a specific programming language. If you can explain to me why this challenge is especially interesting with these I/O requirements, I will gladly revert my downvote.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I personally don't think a challenge is bad because golfing languages can't participate, but that's just my personal opinion, take it as you will. Also can you elaborate on the runtime requirements? I don't see anything pertaining to runtime in the question description

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Are you referring to the requirement that it be a REPL requiring reading from STDIN and writing to STDOUT in a loop?  Do you have a suggestion on how to fix this challenge?

Comment: @musicman523 I don't necessarily think that either; I was going more for the other points. Maybe I shouldn't have said that.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah My suggestion is to take a list of the commands and return the final result, or even just execute each step and print each result individually (because of `L` and `l`).

Comment: regarding `p` command what's an *address*? line number? byte offset?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino If you had issues you have had several years to raise them in sandbox.

Comment: @Christopher You say "several years" which seems to imply that it's a very old sandbox post. I wouldn't have seen it then because I only review things that are linked in chat by our Feeds. If you had linked it along for final feedback before posting I would have been glad to give feedback. Anyway, I see you have added some edits and I think it's significantly better now so if you edit it just to unlock my vote, I will upvote this challenge now also that I've taken a closer look at it. thanks :)

Comment: (    by the way, I did a blank edit so I could revert my downvote and upvote, in case you were wondering about the edit :)    )

Comment: I feel a gif showing the functionality of the line editor would be very useful.

Comment: @KritixiLithos yeah but I would have to make an answer first :/

Comment: @HyperNeutrino thanks that makes sense

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I don't know all that many golfing languages, but Pyth is perfectly capable of handling input in this way, and many golfing languages are able to call out to specialized functions at a high byte cost.

Comment: -1 because it would've been simple enough to have the program take a file and a list of commands, without requiring it to be an interactive shell.

Comment: @mbomb007 so you want your text editor to be not interactive? This challenge is based on real stuff.

Comment: "Based on real stuff" != "real stuff"

Comment: @mbomb007 but this is a actual piece of code that could be used irl. So practical language work better

Comment: Nothing about code-golf is practical.

Comment: I had the weird idea to implement this in 6502 assembly for a C64 :D Not sure whether I'll get somewhere, but the relation (old-fashioned tool for old-fashioned machine) is somehow funny. Won't be the greatest byte-count though ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen if you do that that would be great

Comment: Hmm, 3767 bytes so far (in form of a BASIC loader, the pure machine program is 979 bytes, but that wouldn't count for golf *g*). prompt, command line parsing, the `A` command and movement commands implemented. This seems to work *so far* ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen do it do it!

Answer (score 7):

### C (gcc), <strike>1288</strike> <strike>1212</strike> <strike>1188</strike> <strike>1171</strike> 1146 bytes

```c
#define P printf(
#define A case
#define B break
#define L(i,e,t,f,s)for(o=i;o e;){strcpy(l[o t],l[o f]);c[o t]=c[s o];}
#define R(m,o){return b<1|b>m?m o:b;}
#define N(f)sscanf(f,"%d,%d",&i,&j)||sscanf(f,",%d",&j)
r,i,j,o,z,c[999],*C,x=1,y=1;char a[999],l[999][999],(*L)[999];D(){L(r,>y,,-1,--)r++?strcpy(l[o],l[o-1]+--x),c[o-1]=x,l[o-1][x]=0:0;c[y++]=strlen(l[o]);x=1;}U(){strcat(*L,l[y]);*C=strlen(*L);L(y+1,<r,-1,,++)--r;*l[r]=c[r]=0;}X(b)R(c[y-1],+1)Y(b)R(r,)main(){for(;;){z=i=y;L=l+--z;C=c+z;j=x;!r||y/r&&x>*C?P"end> "):P"%d,%d> ",y,x);scanf("%[^\n]%*c",a)?a[2]*=!!a[1],N(a)?y=Y(i+(i<0|*a=='+')*y),x=X(j+(j<0||strchr(a+1,'+'))*x):0:(*a=D(),scanf("%*c"));switch(*a){A'e':y=r;x=c[r-1]+1;B;A'b':y=1;x=1;B;A'L':for(o=y-4;++o<y+2;)o<0^o<r&&P"%c%s\n",o^z?' ':'>',l[o]);for(o=x+1;--o;)P" ");P"^\n");B;A'l':puts(*L);B;A'p':i=1;j=0;N(a+2);for(o=Y(i)-1;o<Y(j);++o)puts(l[o]);B;A'A':y=r++;strcpy(l[y],a+2);x=c[y]=strlen(a+2);++x;++y;B;A'i':D();--y;x=X(0);A'r':strcpy(*L+x-1,a+2);*C=strlen(*L);x=1;++y>r&&++r;B;A'I':o=strlen(a+2);memmove(*L+x+o-1,*L+x-1,*C-x+1);*C+=o;memcpy(*L+x-1,a+2,o);x+=o;B;A'd':**L?**L=*C=0,x=1:U();y=y>r?r:y;B;A'j':y<r&&U();}}}
```

### [Demo](https://repl.it/JFOI/7)

First time trying to do something like this, so there are probably some missed opportunities for making it smaller. (Thanks Jerry Jeremiah for pointing out some)

Here's a (slightly) more readable version:

```c
// often used functions/keywords:
#define P printf(
#define A case
#define B break

// loops for copying rows upwards/downwards are similar -> macro
#define L(i,e,t,f,s)for(o=i;o e;){strcpy(l[o t],l[o f]);c[o t]=c[s o];}

// range check for rows/columns is similar -> macro
#define R(m,o){return b<1|b>m?m o:b;}

// checking for numerical input is needed twice (move and print command):
#define N(f)sscanf(f,"%d,%d",&i,&j)||sscanf(f,",%d",&j)

// room for 999 rows with each 999 cols (not specified, should be enough)
// also declare "current line pointers" (*L for data, *C for line length),
// an input buffer (a) and scratch variables
r,i,j,o,z,c[999],*C,x=1,y=1;char a[999],l[999][999],(*L)[999];

// move rows down from current cursor position
D()
{
    L(r,>y,,-1,--)
    r++?strcpy(l[o],l[o-1]+--x),c[o-1]=x,l[o-1][x]=0:0;
    c[y++]=strlen(l[o]);
    x=1;
}

// move rows up, appending uppermost to current line
U()
{
    strcat(*L,l[y]);
    *C=strlen(*L);
    L(y+1,<r,-1,,++)
    --r;
    *l[r]=c[r]=0;
}

// normalize positions, treat 0 as max
X(b)R(c[y-1],+1)
Y(b)R(r,)

main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        // initialize z as current line index, the current line pointers,
        // i and j for default values of positioning
        z=i=y;L=l+--z;C=c+z;j=x;

        // prompt:
        !r||y/r&&x>*C?P"end> "):P"%d,%d> ",y,x);

        // read a line of input (using scanf so we don't need an include)
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c",a)?

        // no command arguments -> make check easier:
        a[2]*=!!a[1],

        // numerical input -> have move command:
        // calculate new coordinates, checking for "relative"
        N(a)?y=Y(i+(i<0|*a=='+')*y),x=X(j+(j<0||strchr(a+1,'+'))*x):0:

        // check for empty input, read single newline and perform <return> command:
        (*a=D(),scanf("%*c"));

        switch(*a)
        {
            A'e':y=r;x=c[r-1]+1;B;
            A'b':y=1;x=1;B;
            A'L':for(o=y-4;++o<y+2;)o<0^o<r&&P"%c%s\n",o^z?' ':'>',l[o]);for(o=x+1;--o;)P" ");P"^\n");B;
            A'l':puts(*L);B;
            A'p':i=1;j=0;N(a+2);for(o=Y(i)-1;o<Y(j);++o)puts(l[o]);B;
            A'A':y=r++;strcpy(l[y],a+2);x=c[y]=strlen(a+2);++x;++y;B;
            A'i':D();--y;x=X(0);
            // Commands i and r are very similar -> fall through from i to r
            // after moving rows down and setting position at end of line:
            A'r':strcpy(*L+x-1,a+2);*C=strlen(*L);x=1;++y>r&&++r;B;
            A'I':o=strlen(a+2);memmove(*L+x+o-1,*L+x-1,*C-x+1);*C+=o;memcpy(*L+x-1,a+2,o);x+=o;B;
            A'd':**L?**L=*C=0,x=1:U();y=y>r?r:y;B;
            A'j':y<r&&U();
        }
    }
}
```

---

This challenge leaves quite a lot of corner cases to explore -- I *guess* I fixed all bugs by now, but if somebody finds one more, please comment. Regarding the revisions, I removed byte counts for earlier versions that contained subtle bugs.

Comment: In the part of `D` after the loop, I think you can save bytes by replacing the references to `o-1` and `o` with `o` ,`--o`, `o`, `o`, `++o`. Also, you can do similar things with `x` in the same area.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline thanks for the hint, I have to check. I think a `--o` for the first `o-1` here would be UB because it's unsequenced with another access of `o` :(

Comment: UB is allowed. Also, try [this](tio.run).

Comment: @CalculatorFeline sure, I thought so, just these sequencing issues might change even between compiler versions :o should I just add an explicit version? And for your link, thanks, but I don't think it supports interactive programs?

Comment: Unfortunately not. However, you can use prespecified sequences of input. May be convenient for testing.

Comment: in c global variables default to int so you should be able to change `int r,v,n,i,j,k,n,o,z,x=1,y=1;` to just `r,v,n,i,j,k,n,o,z,x=1,y=1;`

Comment: `r,v,n,i,j,k,n,o,z,x=1,y=1;` contains n twice.

Comment: Wow, stupit glitch, thanks

Comment: Hehe, so far I mostly focused on implementing the logic in a "clever" way .. these are good ideas, thank you! (and give me some time to improve this solution please)

Comment: And I don't think you need a space between your macro-function names and their definitions.

Comment: @ZacharyT indeed, thanks! With some other things I just spotted, another 17 bytes saved :)

Comment: Also, `#define P printf` => `#define P printf(` and change all `P`'s accordingly.

Comment: There are some #defines you can make to get rid of duplication and make it shorter. One is `#define Z b){return(b<1||b` and another is `#define W(t,u,v,w)for(o=t;o u;){strcpy(l[o v].d,l[o w].d);l[o v].c=l[` replaced with `W(r,>y,,-1)` and `W(y+1,<r,-1,)`

Answer (score 5):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>747 807 829</s> 807 bytes

```
func d(D){if(D>0){for(;D<NR;)f[D++]=f[D+1];NR--}else{for(c=NR;x>-D;x--)f[x+1]=f[x];NR++}}
{f[r=NR]=$0}
END{while(1){printf"%s,%d>",r==NR?"end":r,c
getline v<"-"
split("  >  ",l,"")
if(v=="e")r=NR
if(v=="b")r=1
if(v=="L"){for(i=-2;i<3;i++)print l[i+3] f[r+i];printf"%"c+1"s\n","^"}if(v=="l")print f[r]
if(v=="d")z=f[r]=""?d(r):f[r]=""
if(v=="j"){f[r]=f[r] f[r+1];d(r+1)}
S=index(v," ")
z=S?substr(v,S+1):v
a=substr(v,1,1)
n=split(z,N,",")
x=N[1]~/[-+].*/?r+N[1]:N[1]
y=N[2]~/[-+].*/?c+N[2]:N[2]
if(!S&&v~/[0-9+-,]+.*/){r=x?x>NR?NR:x:x=="0"?NR:r
C=length(f[r])
c=n>1?y>C?C:y:c}
if(a=="p")for(i=x?x:1;i<=(y?y:NR);)print f[i++]
if(a=="r"||a=="i"||a=="I"){k=substr(f[r],c)
if(a=="i"){if(c<length(f[r])){d(-r-1);f[r+1]=k}f[r]=substr(f[r],1,c) z (a=="I"?k:"")}if(a="a"||a=="A"){if(a=="A")r=NR;r=r+1;d(r);f[r]=z}}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZLLbtswEEX3/Ap10ARiSTZmsiplSijsLgoEWthLVwUcPRLWgmpQjiNbUX/dHeoRWAuSQx7dmbnk9m13uRSvVepl/pK2pvCX4Yy2xV/rB8t5vAposVkylmg3ySSIV0J0eVnnPZJqJJpQLINGCCQbRJBsHMdY15G22FhkEv151pEf8bJ9ezFl7kva7q2pDgXc1PwmC4FbjVgEeZWBsjwlz/mhNFXuHecggNT70hx88LzQ84CXHIASLPWoNeRAXYYpfHKhnKJHGFoxWtwHZv4QGMZon9krN4Y9JB7Wx0wSTNVAyiTUvyrg8Bu6UaWE8R@Ek0k6A3rWbkMDRJlvqRqDCfjjcrstN/R50D4EmaQdWWtTZXnjHzl42MtZr6P69ak@WNxZI6GOZKs/diSXlFR6cOHMY47lUdLoeCOTf3cbwZKvX@4iy1ys3EBOeHZ/dZYyFys3uPo@rW9vj3g6E9@Y4AlDhLZWN1ET4i3EK9WoBluYgVtbstBlXj0fXnzXCiWprkIZncJFtFAnlXZOcYv4HuhgNuooiX5r/xSdVLyiwYeBeAHJxFt4f3ezGeef6Nhu6tql4imdWAP940zn15XQNvOFFZIGg7161/WOX0tIFPHOnj8kiHYK307Xi8J2zPt90B6X7jUFVqOeu61eOtHnDr/L5T8)

Removing the `else`s makes the lines a bit shorter/readable but the cursor assignment is a bit more complicated.

Just for giggles, I created a version to add a bit more "functionality":

`q` quits the program

`w <outfile[defaults to input file]>` writes the changes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZLfb5swEMff@SvYaa3wjNfQPs3EoCqkUqWWh@QxY1LKj9YLYpmhCYGyfz0786MKDzZ3/vh7d77bHnfnc/ZexGZiBaSVmRV4M9Jmf5TlBvNw5ZJsE1AaCb05kRuuGOvSvEx7JBZI1B4L3JoxJGtEkKw1R2nXGW22UchE4uusM5Zh0B7fZJ5aDmn3ShZVBlelfZV4YCuBmA9pkQBXdmy8plUui9Q8zIGBUe5zWVlgmp5pgp3bAMTAVA9CQApER5jMF206k/UEQylSsFtXzu9cSSnpI5v5RtK7yMT8qIzcKRuIqQPlzwJs@AXdqJLDeAfhaJJOgDRCOwSAn1iK8NGYgN86tnbppY@Dz4cgdcgk/BdIWsvKWAtZJGltHWwwsbJGrP3y/aWsFHrWyPODsRWfHsd2iFGI4U0aO7QxWWLUItw40b@bDaPR9283vqLa5noxTnh2e3EWU21zvehsv6yvrw94OmM/KLMjighplaj92sOehCte8xqznYH@V8ZC5GnxWr1ZujBixKLwHP/kLfwFP/G404pbxI9Y/4NohDj4D49Py/D@eckbd@jGTDein67pYWXkPXxe3QMZOEyBO9g4YZ38Ew9X5OICDuXEK/j40Lsc90cMvZseTGdpx2RiJfRTHs8viyBtYjHFHOIOfRK7rm/dpYSDImZjWkMAf8dxCLteFLZj3PtBe/zVY@kqgXq67b10JJoOv/P5Pw)

Comment: Not getting a caret for column position with `L` command here...

Comment: Ah. I didn't see that requirement. Thanks for finding that @FelixPalmen

Comment: Working now! I also see some requirements interpreted differently from my solution, maybe the challenge should be more precise here...

Comment: Which ones? Perhaps some things are open to interpretation?

Comment: my character-index in a line is 1-based, you use 0-based. EOF position in my program is one after the last character of the last line, in your program its the first character of the line after the last line. My prompt shows only `end>` at the EOF position, yours shows `end,[col]>` in the last line. both aren't *exactly* what is specified I guess ...

Comment: Those were definitely left out of the spec.  Perhaps that was to on purpose to allow for simplifications in different languages?

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to include a write command when I first spec this thing. Good call.

Answer (score 5):

### 6502 Assembly (C64, BASIC loader), <strike>5761</strike> 5352 bytes

```
0fOa=49152to50573:rEb:pOa,b:nE:sY49152
1dA162,54,134,1,162,1,134,7,134,8,202,142,0,96,134,251,162,96,134,21,162,128
2dA142,145,2,162,23,142,24,208,166,8,169,0,160,253,32,98,194,32,126,195,32,173
3dA195,166,2,240,103,202,202,16,2,162,0,142,160,191,173,162,191,201,69,240,93
4dA201,66,240,95,201,204,240,97,201,76,240,96,201,80,240,100,201,193,240,99,201
5dA73,240,123,201,82,240,122,201,201,240,121,201,68,240,123,201,74,240,122,162
6dA0,32,108,196,165,34,166,251,32,81,194,201,255,240,10,133,8,170,169,0,160,253
7dA32,98,194,160,0,177,253,170,232,165,35,201,255,208,2,165,7,32,81,194,133,7
8dA16,134,32,156,194,76,30,192,169,0,133,35,240,204,169,1,133,35,208,198,76,76
9dA193,166,8,32,198,193,76,30,192,76,233,192,166,251,232,134,251,134,8,169,0
10dA160,253,32,98,194,169,0,168,145,253,200,132,7,32,244,193,76,30,192,76,153
11dA193,76,178,193,32,244,193,76,30,192,76,45,193,32,8,195,76,30,192,166,251
12dA240,249,162,1,134,34,202,134,35,162,2,173,160,191,240,3,32,49,196,165,34
13dA166,251,32,81,194,201,255,208,2,169,1,133,34,166,251,165,35,201,255,208,2
14dA169,0,32,81,194,141,37,193,166,34,32,198,193,166,34,224,255,240,190,232,134
15dA34,208,242,160,0,177,253,208,17,165,8,197,251,208,5,198,8,200,132,7,32,8
16dA195,76,30,192,152,145,253,200,132,7,208,245,166,251,240,70,166,8,160,3,202
17dA240,6,200,202,240,2,200,202,232,140,120,193,142,122,193,228,8,240,7,169,32
18dA32,210,255,208,5,169,62,32,210,255,32,198,193,160,255,162,255,136,240,4,228
19dA251,208,219,169,32,166,7,32,210,255,202,208,250,169,94,32,210,255,169,13,32
20dA210,255,76,30,192,32,156,194,198,8,160,0,177,253,133,7,230,7,32,244,193,230
21dA8,162,1,134,7,76,30,192,160,0,166,7,202,138,145,253,32,244,193,230,8,162,1
22dA134,7,76,30,192,169,193,160,219,32,98,194,174,219,193,232,142,229,193,174
23dA220,193,142,230,193,174,255,255,240,16,142,236,193,160,0,185,255,255,32,210
24dA255,200,192,255,208,245,169,13,76,210,255,165,253,24,101,7,141,38,194,141
25dA57,194,165,254,105,0,141,39,194,141,58,194,173,38,194,109,160,191,141,41
26dA194,173,39,194,105,0,141,42,194,160,0,177,253,56,229,7,48,11,170,24,189,255
27dA255,157,255,255,202,16,247,174,160,191,202,16,1,96,189,164,191,157,255,255
28dA202,16,247,160,0,177,253,24,109,160,191,145,253,165,7,24,109,160,191,133,7
29dA96,141,93,194,201,255,240,9,201,0,240,4,224,255,16,1,138,96,141,154,194,141
30dA146,194,140,153,194,200,140,145,194,202,138,41,7,168,138,74,74,74,170,169,0
31dA24,202,48,4,105,3,144,249,141,161,191,185,129,197,41,3,109,161,191,105,96
32dA141,255,255,185,129,197,41,240,141,255,255,96,166,251,232,134,251,142,172
33dA194,169,195,160,120,32,98,194,162,255,202,142,194,194,228,8,240,16,48,14
34dA169,195,160,117,32,98,194,32,101,195,162,255,16,220,173,120,195,141,244,194
35dA141,235,194,173,121,195,141,245,194,141,236,194,160,0,177,253,141,240,194
36dA198,7,56,229,7,72,165,7,145,253,104,170,142,255,255,240,11,160,255,177,253
37dA157,255,255,136,202,208,247,162,1,134,7,166,8,228,251,240,3,232,134,8,96
38dA166,8,228,251,240,86,232,169,195,160,53,32,98,194,173,53,195,141,39,195,173
39dA54,195,141,40,195,160,0,177,253,174,255,255,240,18,142,48,195,24,105,255
40dA145,253,168,189,255,255,145,253,136,202,208,247,166,8,232,228,251,240,30
41dA142,79,195,169,195,160,120,32,98,194,162,255,232,142,95,195,169,195,160,117
42dA32,98,194,32,101,195,162,255,208,222,198,251,96,173,117,195,141,114,195,173
43dA118,195,141,115,195,174,255,255,189,255,255,157,255,255,202,16,247,96,165,8
44dA197,251,144,22,160,0,177,253,197,7,16,14,162,0,189,137,197,32,210,255,232
45dA224,5,208,245,96,165,8,32,196,196,169,44,32,210,255,165,7,32,196,196,162,3
46dA208,225,162,0,134,2,134,204,32,228,255,240,251,36,21,240,17,166,2,224,30
47dA240,241,32,210,255,157,162,191,232,134,2,16,230,201,13,208,19,169,0,166,2
48dA157,162,191,230,204,169,32,32,210,255,169,13,76,210,255,201,20,208,203,166
49dA2,240,199,32,210,255,202,134,2,16,191,141,11,196,141,22,196,32,117,197,160
50dA0,189,162,191,240,44,201,43,208,7,169,1,133,255,232,208,9,201,45,208,8,169
51dA255,133,255,232,189,162,191,240,19,201,48,48,15,201,58,16,11,153,194,191
52dA232,200,192,3,16,2,48,232,96,142,69,196,160,0,132,25,132,32,136,132,34,132
53dA35,169,25,32,244,195,224,255,240,10,142,81,196,32,31,197,133,34,162,255,189
54dA162,191,201,44,208,18,232,142,99,196,169,32,32,244,195,224,255,240,5,32,31
55dA197,133,35,96,32,49,196,169,1,36,25,240,36,16,21,165,34,197,8,48,6,169,1
56dA133,34,208,22,165,8,56,229,34,133,34,208,13,165,8,24,101,34,133,34,144,4
57dA169,0,133,34,169,1,36,32,240,36,16,21,165,35,197,7,48,6,169,1,133,35,208,22
58dA165,7,56,229,35,133,35,208,13,165,7,24,101,35,133,35,144,4,169,0,133,35,96
59dA32,215,196,162,0,189,194,191,240,3,32,210,255,232,224,3,208,243,96,133,20
60dA32,117,197,162,8,160,2,185,194,191,201,5,48,5,105,2,153,194,191,136,16,241
61dA160,2,165,20,10,133,20,185,194,191,42,201,16,41,15,153,194,191,136,16,242
62dA202,208,215,173,196,191,9,48,141,196,191,160,1,185,194,191,240,8,9,48,153
63dA194,191,136,16,243,96,173,196,191,208,19,173,195,191,141,196,191,173,194
64dA191,141,195,191,169,0,141,194,191,240,232,160,2,185,194,191,240,5,41,207
65dA153,194,191,136,16,243,162,8,160,125,24,185,69,191,144,2,9,16,74,153,69,191
66dA200,16,242,165,20,106,202,208,1,96,133,20,160,2,185,194,191,201,8,48,5,233
67dA3,153,194,191,136,16,241,48,211,169,0,141,194,191,141,195,191,141,196,191
68dA96,0,96,192,33,129,225,66,162,69,78,68,62,32
```

### [Demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"edldr.prg":"data:;base64,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"%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"edldr.prg"%7D%7D)

This entry is *just for fun* and will probably never reach a decent byte count. It's just because the challenge is about some "ancient" tool, why not implement it for an ancient machine ;)

[image: See it in action here]

In the course of creating this thing, I was reminded once again that the C64 system doesn't provide any sensible way of converting between strings and integers -- only strings and floats are covered and this is ridiculous, so this piece of code contains own conversion routines. In fact, the only OS routines called are `GETIN` (read a single character from keyboard) and `CHROUT` (write a single character to the screen).

Now, assembly is probably the "least golfy" language ever. For how to "golf" this, my idea as seen here is a BASIC loader, writing the bytes of the final binary to some memory location and jumping there. It's a working BASIC program this way ;) If anyone has a better idea how to golf this, please leave a comment!

The text buffer is quite limited, using up the space between `$6000` and `$BFFF` (BASIC ROM is turned off as it's not needed) and the program itself resides at `$C000`. All in all, there's room for 255 lines with 95 characters each, and the program doesn't do *any* bounds checking, so playing with it, make sure your lines don't grow too large ;)

Finally, [look here for the readable source](https://github.com/Zirias/c64ed/tree/eba2a6e8247b8eaae869110afe910729e502a948), including my "golfing tool".

---

As this is pretty limited stuff, and the C64 *can* do better, here comes the "deluxe edition" using 80 columns display. To do this, the Kernal must be deactivated, so basic things like a keyboard driver, a font, bitmap manipulation logic for output, interrupt handling etc must be included, therefore it's quite a challenge to fit all this in the 4K area `$C000-$CFFF` (and this is needed for loading the program from a BASIC program to work).

Some random facts about this version:

- fits in the 4K, <strike>but narrowly ... got 6 "spare" bytes now</strike> <strike>3686</strike> 3841 bytes ;)
- the basic loader is <strike>13743</strike> <strike>13385</strike> 13963 bytes (used the saved bytes for new feature "line editing")
- screen color and sprite data is hidden in the ram "below" the MMIO area `$D000-$DFFF`
- The PC-style text cursor is a "hardware cursor", using a sprite
- the bitmap uses the area `$E000-$FF3F`, freely accessible because the kernal is switched off
- There's an additional command implemented: `q` exits the editor
- Extra feature: command line editing using cursor `RIGHT` and `LEFT`, Pos1 (`HOME`), End (`SHIFT + HOME`) and backspace (`DEL`)

[image: Screenshot of 80col version]

### [Demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"deluxed.prg":"data:;base64,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"%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"deluxed.prg"%7D%7D)

Program to type in yourself, if you want 80s computer mag feeling:

```
0fOa=49152to52992:rEb:pOa,b:nE:sY49152
1dA162,2,181,0,157,0,207,232,208,248,173,32,208,133,2,173,33,208,133,3,173,17
2dA208,133,5,120,169,0,141,21,208,169,52,133,1,169,15,162,0,32,67,196,32,96,196
3dA162,127,169,0,157,0,218,202,16,250,169,240,141,18,218,141,21,218,169,104,141
4dA248,223,169,53,133,1,169,25,141,0,208,169,50,141,1,208,169,0,141,16,208,141
5dA29,208,141,23,208,141,28,208,169,1,141,39,208,141,27,208,141,21,208,169,228
6dA141,250,255,169,195,141,251,255,169,0,141,14,221,141,4,221,141,5,221,169,129
7dA141,13,221,169,1,141,14,221,173,0,221,41,252,141,0,221,173,24,208,133,4,32
8dA241,195,32,39,196,169,0,133,6,133,7,141,32,208,88,162,1,134,46,32,156,196
9dA120,32,25,196,173,0,221,9,3,141,0,221,165,4,141,24,208,169,55,133,1,169,1
10dA141,13,221,173,13,221,165,5,141,17,208,165,2,141,32,208,165,3,141,33,208
11dA169,0,141,21,208,162,2,189,0,207,149,0,232,208,248,88,96,133,10,169,0,133
12dA11,165,10,10,38,11,10,38,11,10,38,11,133,10,169,1,24,101,10,133,10,169,203
13dA101,11,133,11,96,169,0,133,9,165,6,10,10,10,10,38,9,10,38,9,10,38,9,133,8
14dA165,9,101,6,105,224,133,9,165,12,10,10,10,144,3,230,9,24,101,8,144,2,230,9
15dA133,8,96,160,224,132,9,200,132,11,160,64,132,10,160,0,132,8,162,50,169,0
16dA168,224,3,48,2,177,10,145,8,200,192,160,208,243,202,240,23,169,159,101,8
17dA133,8,144,3,230,9,24,169,160,101,10,133,10,144,218,230,11,176,214,96,72,132
18dA21,76,199,193,72,132,21,201,13,240,15,201,17,240,30,32,241,193,230,7,160,80
19dA196,7,208,52,160,0,132,7,230,6,160,25,196,6,208,40,198,6,32,59,193,240,33
20dA169,32,164,7,240,5,136,132,7,16,19,160,79,132,7,164,6,240,5,136,132,6,16,6
21dA160,0,132,7,240,3,32,241,193,165,6,10,10,10,105,50,141,1,208,169,0,141,16
22dA208,165,7,10,10,144,4,238,16,208,24,105,24,144,3,238,16,208,141,0,208,32
23dA229,195,104,164,21,96,24,74,176,67,32,235,192,160,7,177,10,41,240,153,13,0
24dA136,16,246,165,7,74,133,12,176,18,32,12,193,160,7,177,8,41,15,25,13,0,145,8
25dA136,16,244,96,32,12,193,160,7,177,8,41,240,74,74,74,74,74,25,13,0,106,106
26dA106,106,145,8,136,16,235,96,32,235,192,160,7,177,10,41,15,153,13,0,136,16
27dA246,165,7,74,133,12,176,25,32,12,193,160,7,177,8,10,10,10,10,10,25,13,0,42
28dA42,42,42,145,8,136,16,237,96,32,12,193,160,7,177,8,41,240,25,13,0,145,8,136
29dA16,244,96,174,113,202,236,114,202,240,11,181,22,202,16,2,162,15,142,113,202
30dA24,96,169,0,133,43,133,38,133,40,169,127,141,0,220,173,1,220,73,255,240,25
31dA170,41,4,240,6,165,43,9,128,133,43,138,41,251,240,9,230,40,32,161,195,105
32dA56,133,38,169,191,141,0,220,173,1,220,73,255,240,25,170,41,16,240,6,165,43
33dA9,64,133,43,138,41,239,240,9,230,40,32,161,195,105,48,133,38,169,223,141,0
34dA220,173,1,220,73,255,240,9,230,40,32,161,195,105,40,133,38,169,239,141,0
35dA220,173,1,220,73,255,240,9,230,40,32,161,195,105,32,133,38,169,247,141,0
36dA220,173,1,220,73,255,240,9,230,40,32,161,195,105,24,133,38,169,251,141,0
37dA220,173,1,220,73,255,240,9,230,40,32,161,195,105,16,133,38,169,253,141,0
38dA220,173,1,220,73,255,240,25,170,41,128,240,6,165,43,9,64,133,43,138,41,127
39dA240,9,230,40,32,161,195,105,8,133,38,169,254,141,0,220,173,1,220,73,255,240
40dA7,230,40,32,161,195,133,38,165,40,208,5,169,128,133,39,96,165,38,197,39,240
41dA51,133,39,162,25,134,41,162,1,134,42,5,43,174,114,202,149,22,202,16,2,162
42dA15,142,114,202,236,113,202,208,8,202,16,2,162,15,142,113,202,96,162,7,74
43dA176,4,202,16,250,96,138,24,96,166,41,240,4,202,134,41,96,166,42,240,4,202
44dA134,42,96,162,1,134,42,76,132,195,133,44,134,45,198,46,208,12,169,24,133,46
45dA169,1,77,21,208,141,21,208,32,141,194,169,255,141,25,208,166,45,165,44,64
46dA120,160,1,140,21,208,160,24,132,46,88,96,169,127,141,13,220,173,13,220,169
47dA1,141,26,208,141,25,208,169,16,141,18,208,173,17,208,41,127,141,17,208,169
48dA196,141,254,255,169,195,141,255,255,96,169,0,141,26,208,141,25,208,169,131
49dA141,13,220,96,173,17,208,9,32,141,17,208,169,121,141,24,208,96,173,17,208
50dA41,223,141,17,208,169,114,141,24,208,96,134,47,10,10,10,10,101,47,162,220
51dA134,48,160,0,132,47,162,4,145,47,200,208,251,230,48,202,208,246,96,169,0
52dA168,133,47,162,224,134,48,162,31,145,47,200,208,251,230,48,202,208,246,160
53dA63,145,47,136,16,251,96,32,121,194,184,176,24,170,16,3,44,115,202,41,127
54dA170,189,116,202,80,2,9,128,201,31,176,3,44,115,202,24,96,162,1,134,56,134
55dA55,202,142,0,96,134,54,166,55,160,57,32,208,198,32,188,199,32,235,199,166
56dA65,240,108,202,202,16,2,162,0,134,49,165,128,201,69,240,99,201,66,240,101
57dA201,108,240,103,201,76,240,102,201,80,240,105,201,97,240,103,201,73,240,124
58dA201,82,240,122,201,105,240,120,201,68,240,121,201,74,240,119,201,81,208,1
59dA96,162,0,32,104,201,165,67,166,54,224,0,240,167,32,191,198,201,255,240,8
60dA133,55,170,160,57,32,208,198,160,0,177,57,170,232,165,68,201,255,208,2,165
61dA56,32,191,198,133,56,16,131,32,0,199,16,63,169,0,133,68,240,203,169,1,133
62dA68,208,197,76,10,198,166,55,32,87,198,80,41,240,42,166,54,232,134,54,134,55
63dA160,57,32,208,198,169,0,168,145,57,200,132,56,32,118,198,16,14,240,82,240
64dA104,32,118,198,16,5,240,122,32,94,199,76,168,196,166,54,240,249,162,1,134
65dA67,202,134,68,162,2,165,49,240,3,32,49,201,165,67,166,54,32,191,198,201,255
66dA208,2,169,1,133,67,166,54,165,68,201,255,208,2,169,0,32,191,198,141,167,197
67dA166,67,32,87,198,166,67,224,255,240,191,232,134,67,208,242,32,0,199,198,55
68dA160,0,177,57,133,56,230,56,32,118,198,230,55,162,1,134,56,208,162,160,0,166
69dA56,202,138,145,57,32,118,198,166,54,228,55,240,124,230,55,162,1,134,56,208
70dA116,160,0,196,54,240,110,177,57,208,24,165,55,197,54,208,5,198,55,200,132
71dA56,32,94,199,160,1,196,55,48,86,132,55,16,82,152,145,57,200,132,56,208,74
72dA166,54,240,70,166,55,160,3,202,240,6,200,202,240,2,200,202,232,140,54,198
73dA142,56,198,228,55,240,7,169,32,32,125,193,208,5,169,62,32,125,193,32,87,198
74dA160,255,162,255,136,240,4,228,54,208,219,169,32,166,56,32,125,193,202,208
75dA250,169,38,32,125,193,169,13,32,125,193,76,168,196,160,50,32,208,198,160,0
76dA177,50,240,15,141,110,198,230,50,177,50,32,125,193,200,192,255,208,246,169
77dA13,76,125,193,165,57,24,101,56,133,50,165,58,105,0,133,51,165,50,101,49,133
78dA52,165,51,105,0,133,53,160,0,177,57,56,229,56,48,8,168,177,50,145,52,136,16
79dA249,164,49,136,16,1,96,185,130,0,145,50,136,16,248,160,0,177,57,24,101,49
80dA145,57,165,56,24,101,49,133,56,96,141,203,198,201,255,240,9,201,0,240,4,224
81dA255,16,1,138,96,140,254,198,200,140,247,198,202,138,41,7,168,138,74,74,74
82dA170,169,0,24,202,48,4,105,3,144,249,133,63,185,244,202,41,3,101,63,105,96
83dA133,255,185,244,202,41,240,133,255,96,166,54,232,134,54,134,64,160,59,32
84dA208,198,198,64,166,64,228,55,240,14,48,12,160,61,32,208,198,32,175,199,166
85dA64,16,227,165,59,141,74,199,165,60,141,75,199,160,0,177,57,141,70,199,198
86dA56,56,229,56,72,165,56,145,57,104,160,0,145,59,170,240,11,160,255,177,57
87dA157,255,255,136,202,208,247,162,1,134,56,166,55,228,54,240,3,232,134,55,96
88dA166,55,228,54,240,74,232,160,61,32,208,198,165,61,141,134,199,165,62,141
89dA135,199,160,0,177,61,240,20,170,177,57,134,64,24,101,64,145,57,168,189,255
90dA255,145,57,136,202,208,247,166,55,232,134,64,228,54,240,21,160,59,32,208
91dA198,230,64,166,64,160,61,32,208,198,32,175,199,166,64,208,231,198,54,96,160
92dA0,177,61,168,177,61,145,59,136,16,249,96,165,55,197,54,144,22,160,0,177,57
93dA197,56,16,14,162,0,189,252,202,32,125,193,232,224,5,208,245,96,165,55,32
94dA192,201,169,44,32,125,193,165,56,32,192,201,162,3,208,225,166,7,134,74,166
95dA6,134,75,160,0,132,65,132,66,132,76,164,76,240,6,169,13,32,125,193,96,32
96dA125,196,176,241,112,86,164,65,192,80,240,233,196,66,240,7,182,127,150,128
97dA136,16,245,32,125,193,166,6,134,72,166,7,134,73,208,8,166,6,228,75,208,2
98dA198,75,153,128,0,200,132,66,230,65,196,65,240,23,185,128,0,32,125,193,165,7
99dA208,10,169,24,197,72,208,4,198,72,198,75,200,16,229,166,72,134,6,166,73,134
100dA7,32,119,193,16,153,201,13,208,4,230,76,208,40,201,11,208,10,166,66,228,65
101dA240,135,230,66,16,30,201,12,208,8,166,66,240,46,198,66,16,18,201,15,208,6
102dA162,0,134,66,16,8,201,16,208,31,166,65,134,66,166,75,134,6,24,165,74,101
103dA66,201,80,133,7,144,6,233,80,133,7,230,6,32,119,193,76,251,199,201,17,208
104dA249,164,66,240,245,136,198,65,132,66,196,65,240,7,182,129,150,128,200,16
105dA245,32,125,193,166,6,134,72,166,7,134,73,164,66,196,65,240,9,185,128,0,32
106dA125,193,200,16,243,169,32,32,125,193,166,72,134,6,166,73,134,7,32,119,193
107dA76,251,199,141,12,201,141,23,201,32,104,202,160,0,181,128,240,43,201,43
108dA208,7,169,1,133,255,232,208,9,201,45,208,7,169,255,133,255,232,181,128,240
109dA19,201,48,48,15,201,58,16,11,153,209,0,232,200,192,3,16,2,48,233,96,134,71
110dA160,0,132,69,132,70,136,132,67,132,68,169,69,32,246,200,228,71,240,9,134
111dA71,32,24,202,133,67,166,71,181,128,201,44,208,17,232,134,71,169,70,32,246
112dA200,228,71,240,5,32,24,202,133,68,96,32,49,201,169,1,36,69,240,36,16,21
113dA165,67,197,55,48,6,169,1,133,67,208,22,165,55,56,229,67,133,67,208,13,165
114dA55,24,101,67,133,67,144,4,169,0,133,67,169,1,36,70,240,36,16,21,165,68,197
115dA56,48,6,169,1,133,68,208,22,165,56,56,229,68,133,68,208,13,165,56,24,101
116dA68,133,68,144,4,169,0,133,68,96,32,210,201,162,0,181,209,240,3,32,125,193
117dA232,224,3,208,244,96,133,212,32,104,202,162,8,160,2,185,209,0,201,5,48,5
118dA105,2,153,209,0,136,16,241,160,2,165,212,10,133,212,185,209,0,42,201,16,41
119dA15,153,209,0,136,16,242,202,208,215,165,211,9,48,133,211,160,1,185,209,0
120dA240,8,9,48,153,209,0,136,16,243,96,165,211,208,14,165,210,133,211,165,209
121dA133,210,169,0,133,209,240,238,160,2,185,209,0,240,5,41,207,153,209,0,136
122dA16,243,162,8,160,125,24,185,84,0,144,2,9,16,74,153,84,0,200,16,242,165,212
123dA106,202,208,1,96,133,212,160,2,185,209,0,201,8,48,5,233,3,153,209,0,136,16
124dA241,48,211,169,0,133,209,133,210,133,211,96,15,15,127,9,5,3,1,7,11,13,17,0
125dA69,83,90,52,65,87,51,88,84,70,67,54,68,82,53,86,85,72,66,56,71,89,55,78,79
126dA75,77,48,74,73,57,44,64,58,46,45,76,80,43,47,94,61,0,15,59,42,124,21,81,19
127dA32,50,0,0,49,10,6,4,2,8,12,14,18,0,101,115,122,36,97,119,35,120,116,102,99
128dA38,100,114,37,118,117,104,98,40,103,121,39,110,111,107,109,48,106,105,41
129dA60,64,91,62,45,108,112,43,63,94,61,0,16,93,42,124,22,113,20,32,34,0,0,33,0
130dA96,192,33,129,225,66,162,69,78,68,62,32,34,20,34,85,119,85,85,0,82,5,34,85
131dA119,85,85,0,34,20,119,68,102,68,119,0,82,5,119,68,102,68,119,0,34,20,34,85
132dA85,85,34,0,82,5,34,85,85,85,34,0,65,34,85,85,85,85,34,0,82,5,80,85,85,85
133dA34,0,0,34,20,102,17,51,119,0,0,82,5,102,17,51,119,0,0,34,20,34,119,68,34,0
134dA0,82,5,34,119,68,34,0,0,34,20,34,85,85,34,0,0,82,5,34,85,85,34,0,0,65,34
135dA85,85,85,51,0,0,82,5,80,85,85,51,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,2,0,102,102,15,6,15,6,6,0
136dA37,113,66,98,18,100,37,0,34,82,4,0,0,0,0,0,36,66,66,66,66,66,36,0,0,82,34
137dA119,34,82,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,32,32,64,1,1,2,2,2,36,36,0,33,83,117,113,81,81,33
138dA0,34,85,17,34,33,69,114,0,23,52,86,113,17,21,18,0,39,65,65,98,82,82,34,0
139dA34,85,85,35,81,81,34,0,0,34,34,0,0,34,34,4,0,16,39,64,39,16,0,0,2,69,33,18
140dA34,64,2,0,32,80,118,81,115,69,39,0,64,64,99,84,84,84,99,0,16,16,50,85,87
141dA84,50,0,16,32,115,37,37,35,33,2,66,64,98,82,82,82,82,0,36,4,37,38,38,38,37
142dA64,32,32,38,39,37,37,37,0,0,0,98,85,85,85,82,0,0,0,99,85,85,99,65,65,0,0
143dA98,84,70,65,70,0,32,32,117,37,37,37,19,0,0,0,85,85,87,119,34,0,0,0,85,37
144dA37,34,82,4,1,2,114,36,34,66,113,0,36,34,34,33,34,34,36,0,82,165,5,6,5,5,6
145dA4,34,37,21,7,5,5,5,0,99,84,84,100,84,84,99,0,103,84,84,86,84,84,103,0,118
146dA69,68,103,69,69,71,0,87,82,82,114,82,82,87,0,21,21,22,22,22,85,37,0,69,71
147dA71,69,69,69,117,0,82,85,117,117,117,85,82,0,98,85,85,101,69,71,67,0,98,85
148dA84,98,97,85,82,0,117,37,37,37,37,37,34,0,85,85,85,85,87,119,37,0,85,85,37
149dA34,34,82,82,0,115,18,34,34,34,66,115,0,6,50,66,114,226,66,54,0,48,64,67,68
150dA68,51,17,34,221,235,221,170,136,170,170,255,173,250,221,170,136,170,170
151dA255,221,235,136,187,153,187,136,255,173,250,136,187,153,187,136,255,221
152dA235,221,170,170,170,221,255,173,250,221,170,170,170,221,255,190,221,170
153dA170,170,170,221,255,173,250,175,170,170,170,221,255,255,221,235,153,238
154dA204,136,255,255,173,250,153,238,204,136,255,255,221,235,221,136,187,221
155dA255,255,173,250,221,136,187,221,255,255,221,235,221,170,170,221,255,255
156dA173,250,221,170,170,221,255,255,190,221,170,170,170,204,255,255,173,250
157dA175,170,170,204,255,253,253,253,253,253,255,253,255,153,153,240,249,240
158dA249,249,255,218,142,189,157,237,155,218,255,221,173,251,255,255,255,255
159dA255,219,189,189,189,189,189,219,255,255,173,221,136,221,173,255,255,255
160dA255,255,248,255,223,223,191,254,254,253,253,253,219,219,255,222,172,138
161dA142,174,174,222,255,221,170,238,221,222,186,141,255,232,203,169,142,238
162dA234,237,255,216,190,190,157,173,173,221,255,221,170,170,220,174,174,221
163dA255,255,221,221,255,255,221,221,251,255,239,216,191,216,239,255,255,253
164dA186,222,237,221,191,253,255,223,175,137,174,140,186,216,255,191,191,156
165dA171,171,171,156,255,239,239,205,170,168,171,205,255,239,223,140,218,218
166dA220,222,253,189,191,157,173,173,173,173,255,219,251,218,217,217,217,218
167dA191,223,223,217,216,218,218,218,255,255,255,157,170,170,170,173,255,255
168dA255,156,170,170,156,190,190,255,255,157,171,185,190,185,255,223,223,138
169dA218,218,218,236,255,255,255,170,170,168,136,221,255,255,255,170,218,218
170dA221,173,251,254,253,141,219,221,189,142,255,219,221,221,222,221,221,219
171dA255,173,90,250,249,250,250,249,251,221,218,234,248,250,250,250,255,156,171
172dA171,155,171,171,156,255,152,171,171,169,171,171,152,255,137,186,187,152
173dA186,186,184,255,168,173,173,141,173,173,168,255,234,234,233,233,233,170
174dA218,255,186,184,184,186,186,186,138,255,173,170,138,138,138,170,173,255
175dA157,170,170,154,186,184,188,255,157,170,171,157,158,170,173,255,138,218
176dA218,218,218,218,221,255,170,170,170,170,168,136,218,255,170,170,218,221
177dA221,173,173,255,140,237,221,221,221,189,140,255,249,205,189,141,29,189,201
178dA255,207,191,188,187,187,204,238,221
```

[Readable source code](https://github.com/Zirias/c64ed/tree/c31a9e3cfb53ffbeea865a3399964fa550198f7b).

Comment: Holy crud you did it

Comment: Hehe yep, it's fun :) "deluxe edition" with 80col text mode coming soon, this is a challenge to fit in 4K (needs a font, a keyboard driver and handling a bitmapped mode for text display -- I think it can be done)

Comment: With now 259 bytes left for additional code and 2306 unused bytes below the I/O area, a command history comes to mind ... (would be enough to hold 28 lines of history) ... doing it in 259 bytes of code seems challenging ;)

Comment: Do it! Plez do it

Comment: I guess I misjudged the complexity of a good command history ;) You have to make sure there aren't two identical adjacent entries and you have to save the "current" line while browsing the history ... seems impossible  to implement this in 259 bytes, I'll have to find some other tricks to reduce size first ;)